# char arrays in c end char

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm reading from a socket into a char array and I want to know when to stop reading. The terminating char sequence is '\r\n\r\n'. If what I read in is smaller than the array size I don't want to loop around anymore. My question is really if I load into the array say 10 characters and it has length 20, what is the array[20] index set to?

Thanks

edit:

Sorry I did mean array[19], setting the last index to NULL as suggested? seems like an appropriate solution. To give some more detail, I need to know when all the data has been read from the socket. I don't know the size of the data to be sent only that it terminates with '\r\n\r\n'

Comment: Assuming you mean the last index (array[19]) unless the array is initialized to zero, garbage ☻┬┬*;►E¦§

Comment: Even if the array is initialized to zero. Check my answer below.

Comment: C arrays are zero based; `array[20]` is off the end of the array. Assuming you mean `array[19]`, its contents are undefined. `memset()` the array to zeros to start with if you want the contents to be predictable.

Comment: The answer you selected is not correct. And it's not NULL, but ASCII NUL. But this way you're still getting garbage in the string. You need to set the NUL right after the string. That is, array index for NUL = size of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is really if I load into the array say 10 characters and it has length 20, what is the array[20] index set to?

It's not set to anything. Feel free to set it to something yourself (for instance, a null terminator).

Answer (score 2):

If it has length 20, then array[20] is outside your array and shouldn't be accessed like that (unless you want to do some sort of wizardy and hacking beyond your explanation).

EDIT: If you meant array[19], then no. You need to set the *NUL* character at array index = size of string received. ASCII *NUL* character `'\0'` is not C *NULL* constant, which for 32-bits machines would be 4-byte long, and that would potentially overwrite data.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in the name of efficiency C does not initialize an array to any known value, so you'll get whatever was leftover in memory.

You can explicitly initialize the array to fix this. A common initialization for a sequence of bytes is zero, which won't match your search string and will act as and end-of-string if you try to process the array as a string.

```
char array[20] = {0}; /* the extra elements are always initialized to 0 as well */
char array2[20];
memset(array2, 0, sizeof(array2));
```

I'll presume you had a typo and meant `array[19]` instead of `array[20]`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, when the array is malloced, the array has whatever is leftover in the malloced chunk of memory. If you copy several chars into the array and want the chars to be read as a string, you have to set the next char after the last char to be '\0'.

Comment: True. But as you can see from the question he does not know what the last character is.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know when to stop reading, you could set the next char in your array to `'\0'` to mark the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the ANSI C standard does not describe what value should be allocated to uninitialized arrays. Consider it to be garbage and assume that nothing can be said about it. Although, I have mostly observed them to be 0 (using gcc). This implementation may vary across compilers.

Also, this value could depend on the previous steps which have modified array[19] (as mOskitO pointed out, array[20] is out of bounds).